# Understanding AsynkCallBack and IAsyncResult

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, callback

I Inherited some old .NET 2.0 code that has extensive use of AsyncCallback / IAsyncResult, I'm trying to get a better understanding on how this works. 
As example, I'm using some code I found here:

```
static void TestCallbackAPM()
    {   
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[100] //Just read first 100 bytes
        string filename = "Moq.dll";
        FileStream strm = new FileStream(filename,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024,
            FileOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Make the asynchronous call
        IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
            new AsyncCallback(CompleteRead), strm);

    }
static void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read Completed");

        FileStream strm = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;

        // Finished, so we can call EndRead and it will return without blocking
        int numBytes = strm.EndRead(result);

        // Don't forget to close the stream
        strm.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Read {0} Bytes", numBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
```

What I don't understand is how *IAsyncResult result* gets passed back into the CompleteRead method. To create IAsyncResult  result I need to pass the CompleteRead delegate into it, but somehow it calls the CompleteRead Method passing itself to it as argument? Thats some Inception stuff.
How does that work? Or its just some .NET under the hood magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not let the variable names confuse you. Here is the call:

```
// Make the asynchronous call
IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
            new AsyncCallback(CompleteRead), strm);
```

And this is your delegate. The parameter in your delegate named `result` has nothing to do with the above `result` variable. They just happen to have the same names. This `result` is actually the last argument above which is `strm`. That is why you can actually cast it to a `FileStream` as you are doing below:

```
static void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // ... code
    FileStream strm = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;
    // ... code
}
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, so basically you can pass ANY object as an IAsyncResult and cast it down later in the delegate?